# Jquery Cascading Drop Down how to trigger the change event for all the dropdowns in the chain Sequencially

Tags: asp.net, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the following jQuery code in my application that drives four cascading dropdowns.  I have seen numerous examples online that force the user to select a value by adding a '--Select a Value---' option. However, what I am trying to do is, for the dropdowns, update automatically in the order if one of them changes.

update 2,3,4 if 1 changes and 3,4 if 2 changes, etc.

Dropdown1 Center Dropdown2 Geo Dropdown3 Sup Dropdown4 Emp

This is the jQuery code I have:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#divParentaccordion').accordion({ autoHeight: false }).accordion({       collapsible: true });
        $('#divGenericaccordion').accordion({ autoHeight: false }).accordion({ collapsible: true });
        $('#<% =ddCenter.ClientID %>').change(getGeo());
        $('#<% =ddGeo.ClientID %>').change(getSup());
        $('#<% =ddSup.ClientID %>').change(getEmp());  
       // Statements i assume should call the function when the event triggers                
    })


    function getGeo() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ObservationsReport.aspx/GetGeoList",
            data: "{center: '" + $('#<% =ddCenter.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                var geos = typeof (response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
                $('#<% =ddGeo.ClientID %>').removeOption(/./);
                for (var i = 0; i < geos.length; i++) {
                    var val = geos[i].Code;
                    var text = geos[i].Description;
                    $('#<% =ddGeo.ClientID %>').addOption(val, text);
                }

            }
        })
    }

    function getSup() {
        var center = $('#<% =ddCenter.ClientID %>').val();
        var geo = $('#<% =ddGeo.ClientID %>').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ObservationsReport.aspx/GetSupList",
            data: "{center:'" + center + "',geo:'" + geo + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                var sups = typeof (response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
                $('#<% =ddSup.ClientID %>').removeOption(/./);
                for (var i = 0; i < sups.length; i++) {
                    var val = sups[i].SOPId;
                    var text = sups[i].Name;
                    $('#<% =ddSup.ClientID %>').addOption(val, text);
                }
            }
        })
    }

    function getEmp() {
        var center = $('#<% =ddCenter.ClientID %>').val();
        var geo = $('#<% =ddGeo.ClientID %>').val();
        var sup = $('#<% =ddSup.ClientID %>').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ObservationsReport.aspx/GetEmpList",
            data: "{center:'" + center + "',geo:'" + geo + "',sup:'" + sup + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                var emps = typeof (response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
                $('#<% =ddEmp.ClientID %>').removeOption(/./);
                for (var i = 0; i < emps.length; i++) {
                    var val = emps[i].Sop_Id;
                    var text = emps[i].Name;
                    $('#<% =ddEmp.ClientID %>').addOption(val, text);
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have recently started programming in jQuery; still not completely familiar with how it handles the events and when.  Please, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The context of what you're trying to do is vague at best.  Can you provide a more concrete example either via link or pasting some before/after images or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you're expecting the population of a box from the ajax call to trigger that select's `onchange`.  This is not the case.  Changes through javascript do not fire `onchange`.  You will need to fire the `onchange` yourself.

For example, try changing `getGeo` to this:

```
function getGeo() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ObservationsReport.aspx/GetGeoList",
            data: "{center: '" + $('#<% =ddCenter.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                var geos = typeof (response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
                $('#<% =ddGeo.ClientID %>').removeOption(/./);
                for (var i = 0; i < geos.length; i++) {
                    var val = geos[i].Code;
                    var text = geos[i].Description;
                    $('#<% =ddGeo.ClientID %>').addOption(val, text);
                }

                // *** CALL getSup directly ***
                getSup() ;

            }
        })
    }
```

The key here is the explicit call to `getSup` as it will not be triggered `onchange`.